# binding a iterable for a single SQL statement

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I wish to issue this query `SELECT code FROM table1 WHERE id IN (1,4,5,6);`.

Is it possible to use some form of `Connection.execute("SELECT code FROM table1 WHERE id IN ?", ...);` and bind the iterable (1,4,5,6) ?